# With handsontable is it possible to add dynamically css class for a specific row or column?

Tags: handsontable

With handsontable, is it possible to dynamically add a class to a row or a column to have custom effects (e.g., row height for a specific row, column background color for a specific row)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created another post asking a related question. If you follow the logic of my example, that is how you create custom classes on a cell by cell basis.

My problem has to do more with adding multiple classes using different selection logic.

[Is there a way to add multiple classes using the renderers method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190903/is-there-a-way-to-add-multiple-classes-using-the-renderers-method)

Answer (score 0):

you can add classes for cell or rows in the renderColumns cb, I used jquery

```
function myFunc(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties){
   // add class to each or speacfic cells,can controled by cell index 
   $(td).addClass("new_cell_class another_class");
   // add class to row
   $(td).closest("tr").addClass("new_row_class");
}
const handsontableSettings = {
     data: [[1,2],[1,2]]
     columns: [{renderer: myFunc}, {}]
}
new Handsontable(document.getElementById("container_id"), handsontableSettings);
```